# magento cart price issue

Tags: magento, cart, discount

I am using Magento 1.8.1.0.
I have defined no catalog price rule.But i am applying special price on some selected products. On product catalog page the price and special price and the discount percent as sale is shown on that product. But when i add these products to the cart it doesn't shows the price of product as it is but it shows the price after applying ((price*specialprice)/100) rule in unit price and subtotal and grand total.
for example:
price is $79
specialprice is $71
sale discount is 10 %
the result wanted in cart (for quantity one) is as
unit price is $71
subtotal is $71
grand total is $71
but it is showing as
unit price is $56.09
subtotal is $56.09
grand total is $56.09

i am new on Magento so please help me soon.
Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry guys....
I have solved this problem myself..
The problem was in (the calculation as i have mentioned) inthe file price.php located in Mage/Bundle/Model/Product...
It is calculating the specialPrice as (finalprice*SpecialPrice)/100.. I just changed it and now everything is going welll....